# Convert char DATETIME to SAS date

Tags: date, datetime, sas, character

I have some de-identified EHR data that includes a contact date for each physician encounter. These large files are .txt and imported as such:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT = WORK.DM1
DATAFILE="T:\DM_DEID\PAT_ENC_DX.txt"
DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
GETNAMES=YES;
DATAROW=2;
RUN;
```

The Contact_Date variable, however is imported as a char type, with informat $21. (see attached image). I have looked a several methods to convert this to a date, without the meaningless timestamp, but nothing has worked yet. The below code has gotten me close, except it only captures the first number of the 'days' and leaves some cells blank (see image 2)
[image]

```
DATA DM1_;
SET DMI;
DATE=INPUT(SUBSTR(CONTACT_DATE,4,10),YYMMDD.);
FORMAT DATE MMDDYYD10.;
RUN;
```

[image]

I get the following error, which Im finding hard to decipher: "Invalid argument to function INPUT at line 66, column6."

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can also supply more information if needed. Thanks.

Comment: `4.10` - is that supposed to be `4,10`?  What's the period?  And why are you starting at 4, is that actually where the first digit of the year is in the string, or is it position 1?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that is supposed to be a comma. I will edit it. When I use 1, instead of 4, the new DATE variable returns null values for everything: ".". I have to admit, I am not the most accomplished SAS coder, so I have been trying just about anything to convert the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the compress function to remove the whitespace (it seems there is randomly some in there), grab the first 10 characters, and then `input()` that.

I also like the `anydtdte.` informat for letting SAS decide on the best

```
data _null_;
contract_date = ' 2004- 12-02 00:00:00';
date = input(substr(compress(contract_date),1,10),anydtdte21.);
put date date9.;
run;
```

Returns:

```
02DEC2004
```

Comment: Brilliant! This worked perfectly, with the exception that I had to replace 'put date date9.;' with 'format date MMDDYY10.;' Thank you.

Comment: I *think* it's just removing whitespace from the front of the string, though it's not 100% clear.  You shouldn't have any 'successes'  at all if there is whitespace in the middle of the date part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you display above, I think `5` is the right place to start the string.

```
DATE=INPUT(SUBSTR(CONTACT_DATE,5,10),YYMMDD.);
```

It looks like it's currently inputting everything up to the first digit of the day, hence why 1-digit days are missing.

Another option is to use `scan`:

```
date = input(scan(contact_date,1,' '),YYMMDD.);
```

`SCAN` separates words, not characters, by a delimiter.

It's also possible there are double byte characters involved above; it's a bit odd that you don't start at 1, so it's possible that 5 would cut off the year; perhaps the `-` character is a unicode character taking up multiple bytes, and that's why it looks shifted over. In that case, the `scan` approach should work, or you might need to start at 1 but include more than 10 characters in your substr.